# ExtJS 6 - pivot without CMD

Tags: cmd, pivot, extjs6

I would like to evaluate the features of pivot grid using simple test html without cmd.
I've read the information from those links but I still couldn't install a working environment
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/co...ivot_grid.html 
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthr...out-Sencha-Cmd
http://se.sencha.com/setup-guide/

I've downloaded the core framework ('ext-6.0.1-trial.zip') 
and pivot addon ('ext-addons-6.0.1-trial.zip') from sencha site 
and unpacked them on my test web server:

www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/ <- framework
www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/package/ <- addon

and tested it calling the pivots in kitchensink example with:
www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html 
in such setup they start without errors.

The target location of the addon is a bit strange for me, 
I was sure I should unpack addon to the package directory of the framework 
www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/package/ 
but then the kitchensink example doesn't work 
(kitchensink calls pivot with ../../../package/pivot )

Now I wonder how should I include framework and addon in own html example,
I've tried something like:

```
<link href="www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/classic/theme-neptune/resources/theme-neptune-all.css">
<script src="www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
<link href="www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/packages/pivot/build/neptune/resources/pivot-all.css">
<script src="www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/packages/pivot/build/pivot.js"'></script>
<script src="www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/packages/exporter/build/exporter.js"'></script>
```

The links are ok (no http error) but the simple pivot is not rendered
and framework couldn't load further classes:
[Ext.Loader] Some requested files failed to load.

What is the correct setup of extjs and pivot without cmd?

Thank you,
Annie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things here.

For the KitchenSink, if you open up [www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/](http://www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/) in your browser you will be shown an index.html. There will be a green button to show the examples which will point to [www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/examples/index.html](http://www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/examples/index.html) (notice the `build` dir in there). Then if you click on the KitchenSink it will load from [www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/examples/kitchensink/](http://www.mydummy.server.org/lib/extjs/ext-6.0.0/build/examples/kitchensink/) (once again, notice the `build` dir). This is due to the KitchenSink being a Cmd app which will build to that `build` dir. The `examples` dir outside the `build` dir is the development version of the app which is why we still provide it for the source.

Next, about how to use the pivot grid's Cmd package outside of the Cmd package. we build the Cmd package so if you look in the package's `build` dir you should see a built JavaScript and CSS file that you can load via `<script>` and `<link>` in your HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Pivot Grid Test</title>

        <link href="http://releases/ext/6.0.1.250/build/classic/theme-neptune/resources/theme-neptune-all.css">
        <script src="http://releases/ext/6.0.1.250/build/ext-all.js"></script>

        <link href="http://localhost/ext-addons-6.0.1/packages/pivot/build/neptune/resources/pivot-all.css">
        <script src="http://localhost/ext-addons-6.0.1/packages/exporter/build/exporter.js"></script>
        <script src="http://localhost/ext-addons-6.0.1/packages/pivot/build/pivot.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Notice I have the `exporter.js` loading before `pivot.js` and this mostly works except that I do see something that I'd call a bug for us. In `pivot.js`, we define `Ext.ux.ajax.PivotSimlet` which extends `Ext.ux.ajax.JsonSimlet` (which is in the framework's `ux` package). This is fine to extend like this but `PivotSimlet` would only be needed if you want to have simulated data in your application (which most wouldn't unless in dev). Two ways you can fix this, remove that class from `pivot.js` or include the `ux`'s JavaScript/CSS (however that package contains a lot of code that you may not need).

Comment: And yes, I have created a bug in our bug tracker to get `PivotSimlet` out of the build.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your explanation.
I've added these classes to get an working example:

```
<script src="http://releases/ext/6.0.1.250/packages/ux/src/ajax/Simlet.js"</script>
<script src="http://releases/ext/6.0.1.250/packages/ux/src/ajax/DataSimlet.js"</script>
<script src="http://releases/ext/6.0.1.250/packages/ux/src/ajax/JsonSimlet.js"</script>
```