# ExtJS 6. How to create a simple pivot grid without cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to create a very simple pivot grid, using `ExtJS 6`. What I have now is `ExtJS 6` library itself and `pg-6.0.2` package containing something related to Pivot Grid. In the past, when there was `Extjs 5` version there was some nice [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.3/guides/components/pivot_grid.html), which explained how to link pivot grid files to the index page:

> {pivotFolder}/packages/PivotGrid/build/PivotGrid.js
>
> {pivotFolder}/packages/PivotGrid/build/{themeName}/resources/PivotGrid-all.css

Now, the structure of `pg-6.0.2` is essentially different. In fact there is no `build/PivotGrid.js` anymore, but there is something like `build/pivot.js`. Is that what we need? I'm not sure of that. Besides, it would be really great if someone could provide a really teeny-weeny example, demonstrating how to code pivot grid (let it be just with one column and one row of data). This code may serve as a starting point:

```
Ext.define("MyPivot.view.Viewport",{
    extend: "Ext.container.Viewport",
    layout: "fit",
    initComponent:function(){
        Ext.apply(this,{
            layout:{
                type: "border"
            },
            items:[{
                region: "center",                
                xtype: "panel",
                title: "My first pivot grid",
                layout: "fit",
                items: [{
                   // I want to add here a pivot grid
                }]                
            }]
        });
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

And how the index page should look like?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/ext-6.0.2/build/classic/theme-triton/resources/theme-triton-all.css" type="text/css" />
 <script src="/ext-6.0.2/build/ext-all.js"></script>
 // what else I should link ???
```

**EDIT**

My root `app.js` file looks like so:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true, disableCaching:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../ext-6.0.2/packages/ux/classic/src/');
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyPivot',
    appFolder: '.',
    autoCreateViewport: true
});
```

And I tried this in my index file:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/ext-6.0.2/build/classic/theme-neptune/resources/theme-neptune-all.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/ext-6.0.2/build/ext-all.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/pg-6.0.2/ext-addons-6.0.2/packages/pivot/build/neptune/resources/pivot-all.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="/pg-6.0.2/ext-addons-6.0.2/packages/pivot/build/pivot.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I load the page I see in the console, that many files are not found. This one - "/Ext/exporter/Excel.js". And this one - "Ext/ux/ajax/JsonSimlet.js". And so the page gets broken. I do not know how to fix all that and I wish there were some more "illustrative" examples in official Sencha documentation concerning Pivot Grid.

**EDIT**
I wish [such](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#outline-pivot-grid) examples contained also index page source code. Otherwise, if you do not know how to link everything, the rest code is of no use to you.

Comment: Could that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741569/extjs-6-pivot-without-cmd

Comment: Yeah. I've solved it. Think, I should delete my question.

Comment: I would suggest you to answer your question with the solution